# Chrome won't load pages after ctrl+alt+delete

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

I noticed that Chrome (the install is a clean vanilla load install per the chrome installation site) has been locking up on me not loading pages after I lock my windows 7 laptop and relogin.  I have to kill it then re-open it to work again. But once I lock ctrl+alt+delete my laptop and log back in Chrome spins even loading google.com.

Has anybody been victim of this behavior?

Comment: Sounds like a system specific configuration since this is not the behavior within a fresh windows 7 virtual machine.

Comment: @Ramhound It's odd...it's only doing this on my laptop at work (where I develop software) but at home it's fine. Been scratching my head with this one for a while.

Comment: That tells me you should refresh the laptop and call it day.  Have you verified the integrity of the system files on the laptop?

Comment: @Ramhound: Ha! Yes, that would be nice. Files are fine and I have even tried uninstalling/reinstalling to bare bones chrome (no bookmarks/ad-ons/extensions/etc.).